# sort alpa numeric field in sql-server 2014

Tags: sql-server

i need to sort alpha numeric field in sql-server 2014.

i need first to sort by text and then by number.

for example:

```
12AA
12AA
20EA
3CA
4BA
70AA
81CA
81CA
8CA
90EA
```

will looks like this

```
12AA
12AA
70AA
4BA
3CA
8CA
81CA
81CA
20EA
90EA
```

anothe example

```
10EA
21C
31CA
81CA
```

will looks like this:

```
**21C
31CA
81CA
10EA**
```

i try something like this:

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section)-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section), LEN(Section))) -- numerical
```

but its not works.

thanks,

Comment: If the field always looks like that (numbers then letters), then it's a matter of sorting by something like `right(i, len(i) - patindex('%[^0-9]%', i) + 1), cast(left(i, patindex('%[^0-9]%', i) - 1) as int)`

Comment: In a perfect world you would be able to split these two values into the two columns the values obviously represent. When you stick two values like this into the same column you are violating 1NF which as you are discovering causes lots of unnecessary pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close

```
...
 Order By 
       Substring(Section,PatIndex('%[A-Z]%',Section) ,25)
      ,Cast(Left(Section,PatIndex('%[A-Z]%',Section)-1 ) as int)
```

Returns

```
SomeField
12AA
12AA
70AA
4BA
3CA
8CA
81CA
81CA
20EA
90EA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this order by clause:

```
order by RIGHT(section,2), CASE WHEN LEN(section)=3 THEN '0'+section else section end asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING(Section, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Section), LEN(Section)),
  CAST(LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Section)-1) AS INT)
```